# Breakpoint to stop when execution reaches any line of code in a certain source file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

My web app runs on angularjs.

I need a breakpoint for the following case:
- my app triggers some angular function
- chrome starts going deep in angular, lots of angular internal stuff is done
- at some point angular calls one of my callback functions.

All my functions are in a file called bundle.js. I would like to set a breakpoint so that whenever a function from bundle.js is called, execution will break.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [blackbox](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing) Angular in DevTools. Then when you step into Angular code Chrome will continue running until non-Angular code is reached.